# Rails and factory patterns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, erb, restful-architecture

Imagine a Rails project that looks up animal celeberties based on their names.  This Rails app is backed by an external service that does the actual lookup.  The service returns back results based on a key.  For example, if I make a request to this external api like [GET] /animal?name=benji, I would get back something like {"type":"dog", "legs":"4", "tail-length":"short", "collar":"blue"}.  However, if I pass in ...?name=flipper to the animal endpoint, I would get back {"type":"dolphin", "color":"gray", "food":"fish"}.  (The data is returned in actual JSON or XML. I am just using pseudo code here to communicate the point.)

My first question is this...  Given that the attributes of the return call vary based on data which is passed in, when unmarshaling a response (for lack of a better term) into a "model" object, does it make sense to implement some type of factory pattern (ala Design Patterns in Ruby, by Russ Olsen, Chapter 13) to create objects of an appropriate class?  Are there other approaches that would make sense?

My next question is this, lets say that I want to display a list of all animals on a web page (using ERB templates.)  Does it make sense to create different partial templates (eg _dolphin.html.erb and _dog.html.erb) and then put a *case* in the main list view that can deligate rendering each list item to an appropriate template.

For example:

list.html.erb...

```
  <ul>
  <% for animal in @animals.each %>
     <li>   
        <% if animal.type == 'dog' %>
          <%= render :partial => 'dog', :locals => {:animal => animal} %>
        <% elsif item.type == 'dolphin' %>
          <%= render :partial => 'dolphin', :locals => {:animal => animal} %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render :partial => 'generic_animal', :locals => {:animal => animal} %>
        <% end %>
      </li>          
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```

(Here animal.type=='dog' is intentional.  I am not using a symbol (:dog) because the data returned back from the API is a string value, and it is used to populate the animal.type attribute.  Bad, I know.)

The project that I am working on is using this approach right now.  (Obivously, I have changed the elements/domain.)  I am wondering if this is a valid approach, and/or if others have dealt with similar problems and how they went about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say create a single model and a single view which contains all possible attributes (can't be an infinite number ;) ).

And then you have an

```
if attribute_x exists then
  display it
end

if attribute_y exists then
  display it
end
```

for each attribute.

If you create a view for each animal this wouldn't be DRY at all, 'cause you'll repeat yourself sooo many times, just knowing that each animal has favorite food and a color, etc.. Another reason: If the API changes a bit, and an animal gathers or looses an attribute you would have to adapt this change.

With just one view, it would be all fine for all time.

If you want to be super-sure that you gather all attributes, you could place an array of all known attributes inside your controller and if there's something unknown: write it to a log file.

---

I'd only choose the way of 'one view per animal' if you want to be able to display things completely different for some animals. But then you could also tell your controller that it should choose another view if `name = 'Donkey Kong'`. you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin.  In my example, I am using animals.  The actual app is probably more like "animals", and "realestate" as two different returned objects, and the views are completely different.  Thanks for the feedback!